# Search in only my repositories for files with a specific name

Tags: github, search

I want all `readme.txt` files in my repos.

I tried this query:

> filename:readme.txt user:emirhanyagci

Changing `user` to `owner` didn't help. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename` isn't a [valid search qualifier](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax). You have to use `path` instead:

> path:readme.txt user:emirhanyagci

will show `readme.txt` files at any depth, an

> path:/^readme.txt/ user:emirhanyagci

(regular expression anchored at the start) will show `readme.txt` files in the root directory of repositories.

Answer (score -1):

### Try the following

`path:**/readme.txt user:your_username`

Replace "your_username" with your actual GitHub username. This query will narrow down the search to files named "readme.txt" within repositories owned by you.

Note that the "user" keyword specifies the owner of the repositories.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW do u think chatgpt is devil, you need answer, then taking from documentation or chatgpt doesn’t mater

Comment: @Venkatesh I don't think it's the devil. I think we should assume that people have already asked it before they come here and that they're looking for a validated answer by a real person.